# Webpack can not resolve "vue-property-decorator" (v10.X) library while it has been installed

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-class-components, vue-property-decorator

I got the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './decorators/Emit'` when tried to import some functionality from the library [vue-property-decorator](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)... Well, I did not ask this question if the cause was simple like forgot to install this package. The package has been installed and presents:

[image]

The IntelliJ IDEA does not display it on files three view somehow, but I still can view it via `go to source` functionality and of course, I check these file via native file system.

[image]

The errors are like:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/vue-property-decorator/lib/index.js 3:0-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './decorators/Emit' in 'C:\Users\XXXX\Package\node_modules\vue-property-decorator\lib'
 @ ./index.ts 1:0-49 2:12-19

ERROR in ../node_modules/vue-property-decorator/lib/index.js 4:0-45
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './decorators/Inject' in 'C:\Users\XXXX\Package\node_modules\vue-property-decorator\lib'
 @ ./index.ts 1:0-49 2:12-19

ERROR in ../node_modules/vue-property-decorator/lib/index.js 5:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './decorators/Model' in 'C:\Users\XXXX\Package\node_modules\vue-property-decorator\lib'
 @ ./index.ts 1:0-49 2:12-19\
```

Usually the errors like these are occurring when forgot some settings of the TypeScript compiler like `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` or `esModuleInterop`. However these errors are the Webpack errors, not TypeScript errors. But just in case, I'll append my TypeScript config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {}
  }
}
```

The Webpack config is:

```js
import Webpack from "webpack";
import Path from "path";
import { VueLoaderPlugin } from "vue-loader";


const webpackConfig: Webpack.Configuration = {

  context: Path.resolve(process.cwd(), "Source"),
  entry: "./index.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: Path.resolve(process.cwd(), "Distributable")
  },
  mode: "development",
  watch: true,

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [ /\.vue$/ ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/u,
        oneOf: [
          {
            resourceQuery: /^\?vue/u,
            use: [ "pug-plain-loader" ]
          },
          {
            use: [
              {
                loader: "html-loader",
                options: {
                  minimize: { caseSensitive: true }
                }
              },
              "pug-html-loader"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [ ".ts" ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};


export default webpackConfig;
```

A had not any problems with `vue-property-decorator` for the `Vue 2.x`. But this is my first experience with version `10.x` for the `Vue 3.x`.

Please don't recommend me the boilerplates created via Vue-cli or Vite - here we are talking about manual setup with Webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add .js extension to your Webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [".js", ".ts"]
},
```

`.js` extension always has to be included in any config, because all your dependencies will be compiled to JavaScript and Webpack has to process those, too.

I cloned your repo and after that Webpack only reported an error about missing `pug` package but installing it solved the issue, then the remaining errors are related to `noUnusedParameters: true` in your tsconfig.json.